# Having various troubles with Insert Into

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an extension I have made and inside this extension there is an "install.sql" file which contains various inserts.

Some of these inserts do it to tables which MAY exist or not depending on the clients site. What I would like to know is how to do for example something like:

"create table if exists" but for an "Insert Into".

This is an example of what im doing:

```
INSERT INTO `#__virtuemart_shipmentmethods_en_gb` 
(virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id, shipment_name, shipment_desc, slug) 
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(vs.virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id) 
FROM `#__virtuemart_shipmentmethods` vs), 'Kiala','', 'kiala');
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered running this is a stored procedure? Something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testprocdure` ()
BEGIN

IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '[database name]' 
AND table_name = '#__virtuemart_shipmentmethods_en_gb') = 1 THEN

INSERT INTO `#__virtuemart_shipmentmethods_en_gb` (virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id, shipment_name, shipment_desc, slug) 
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(vs.virtuemart_shipmentmethod_id) FROM `#__virtuemart_shipmentmethods` vs), 'Kiala','', 'kiala');

ELSE

-- Handle if the table doesnt exists
SELECT ''; -- This is just so the SP wont return a error after the else. Remove this when you want to run it
END IF;
END
```

You could also make use of parameters if you have variable changing.

Then the create syntax should look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testprocdure` (IN p_TableName VARCHAR(100))
```

Change the name of the parameter and datatype to fit your needs.

Could this maybe help?

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if i got your question right....

you want to insert somesthing and if its already there you want to update ?

if yes, you propably looking for **[THIS HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-on-duplicate.html)** otherwise your question is set up bad or its to late for me to get it right :)

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

if you don't know if the table exists than you might should check all befor
usual i use pdo, don't know what you use but my solution would be some like this

```
$result  = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '#__virtuemart_shipmentmethods_en_gb'");
$tExists = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
if(!$tExists)
    // Create Table Code here
```

Comment: I thought I explained myself pretty well sorry :P. My issue is that there may be a table named `#__virtuemart_shipmentmethods_en_gb` or there may not but even though my extension is going to try to do an insert. If such table doesnt exist it will give back an error and wont continue with the installation. I want to know how to check if the table im trying to insert data into exists.

Comment: You need to add IGNORE to the syntax also INSERT IGNORE INTO right?

Comment: oh, in that case you should check before, i will update my post

Comment: guess Kay Nelson post is what you looking for